# I can't modify my store opening hours on prestashop 1.6.1.10

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

my problem is that when I edit the opening hours of one of my stores (preferences > store contacts > and then modify one of my 5 stores) something goes wrong. I want my shop to stay open from Monday to Saturday in these hours 09.00 - 12.30; 15.30 - 19.30, but for some reason in the Saturday field I can write only these hours 09.00 - 12.30 because if in this day I write also 15.30 - 19.30 prestashop deletes every other hour of every other day (after I clicked save, I go back and all the fields of all the days are empty; ).
 How can I solve it? Are there some time limitations I am not aware of?

see the images if you don't understand just ask again

Thanks
Lorenzo

[it doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeNkC.jpg)

[it works just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcDW6.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the field in database for the store hours is `varchar 254`, and encodes all hours in the same field with serialize. It's not related to all the time being equal, but it you use less chars in each field it will allow you to same it correctly. Or, if you have access to the database, you can increase the field `'hours'` in table `'__DB_PREFIX__store'` to greater than 254.

In version 1.7 it uses json_encode, it's smaller, but cant use a field like '09.00 - 12.30; 15.30 - 19.30; 20:30 - 23:30' and no warning is issued.

Comment: Related to [this PR on Github](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/7557)

Comment: Yes. I created a previous one https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/7555 with just a different approach (get the warning) but guess that increasing the field size is better.

Comment: thanks to all even if at the end I cancelled a few spaces and solved in this way.